# jasper exception occure during connectivity to SQLServer 2008 R2

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<form name="form" method="post" >
<b>Select a country:</b> </td>
<select name="sel"><option value=""><---Select---></option>
<%
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();


Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://subversion/sql2k8:1433/career","sa","Cloud#123");

PreparedStatement psmnt = con.prepareStatement("select * from country ");
ResultSet results = psmnt.executeQuery();
while(results.next()){
String name = results.getString(2);
 String id = results.getString(1);
%><option value="<%= name %>"><%=name%></option>
<%} results.close(); psmnt.close(); %>
</select><br>
```

---

and the error which comes:-

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /1.dropdown_insert.jsp at line 13
```

---

```
10: 
11: 
12: 
13: Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://subversion/sql2k8:1433/career","sa","Cloud#123");
14: 
15: PreparedStatement psmnt = con.prepareStatement("select * from country ");
16: ResultSet results = psmnt.executeQuery();
```

---

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for connection string - `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver`**://subversion/sql2k8**`:1433/career`.
2. Use `try-catch` block and printstacktrace to get proper error msg.

Comment: thanks for replay.. i had put the try- catch block and it is showing the error :-


java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect